# Excel VBA to color only text that has not been previously colored

Tags: vba, excel

I need code that colors text that is only automatic. Specifically, I have text that is clean and then text that is blue and bolded. I want the clean text to become red, bolded, and with a strikethrough. This is the code I am working with and the entire cell both clean and blue bolded text become red, bolded, and strikedthrough.

```
Sub KeepBlueBold()
  'keeps bluebold cell
   Dim Cell    As Range
  For Each Cell In Selection
  KeepBlueAddRed Cell
  Next Cell
End Sub


Sub KeepBlueAddRed(Cell As Range)
 Dim iCh        As Integer
 For iCh = 1 To Len(Cell)
  With Cell.Characters(iCh, 1)
If .FOnt.ColorIndex <> 1 Then
Text = Text & .Text


End If
End With
Next iCh
Cell.Value = Text
Cell.Characters.FOnt.Strikethrough = True
Cell.Characters.FOnt.Bold = True
Cell.Characters.FOnt.ColorIndex = 3
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have mixed formats in any given cell?

Answer (score 0):

The code below should work, given you have a range already selected.

```
Sub KeepBlueBold()

    Dim c As Range

    For Each c In Selection.Cells
        If c.Font.ColorIndex = 1 Then
            c.Font.ColorIndex = 3
            c.Font.Bold = True
            c.Font.Strikethrough = True
        End If
    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Can you explain "given you have a range already selected" Do you mean

Comment: I mean that since you didn't explained which range you would be using, for this code work, you should select the range manually (using the mouse) and then run the macro.
But if all the cells you're trying to change are in the column A, for example, you could put:  
    Set c = Range("A:A")